# Bootstrap x editable post url to controller codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am trying to make column row editable using x editable. I'm using codeigniter framework. When I post url to controller using Ajax post, value didn't post into array in controller.

this is my script

[image]

this is my view

```
  <td class="numeric"><center><a href="#" class="status_order" name="status" data-type="select" 
                                data-pk="<?=$data['id_faktur'];?>" data-value="<?=$data['status'];?>"
                                data-title="STATUS PEMBELIAN">
                                <?=$data['status'];?></a></center></td>
```

this is my controller

```
public function edit() {

    $data = array (
        'status' => $this->input->post('value')
        );

    $this->admin_order_model->update_status($value, $data);
    redirect('admin/produk/penjualan');
}
```

[image]

[image]

i don't know why array is empty... help me please

Comment: Try with `async: false, `

Comment: replace your ajax `error` line with this: `error: function( xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){console.log(errorThrown)}` and check your console for what errors you have. Most likely a 404, meaning that your URL might be wrong, since it is not reaching the desired method.